# Any other built-in light colors besides "gray" in css?

Tags: css, colors

Those fit for background colors.

I need as many as possible:)

Answer (score 2):

You can always compile your own colors:

```
background: rgb(245, 255, 255);
```

where the first property is the ammount of Red, the second is the ammount of Green and the third is the ammount of Blue.

As long as you keep the values high (where 255 is max) the color will be light ;)

Comment: I don't quite understand why you say :As long as you keep the values high (where 255 is max) the color will be light

Comment: Yes. If all three values in the rgb-"function" are high, you will get a light color. In my example I set the red to 245 and the green and blue to 255, this gives us a light color with fairly more green and blue than red. You get it? You can play around with rgb-values and colors here: http://kuler.adobe.com/#create/fromacolor

Answer (score 1):

CSS 2.1 only defines [16 named colours.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#color-units)

Most browsers support a much larger set, including colours from [SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#ColorKeywords). These are included in [CSS 3 Colors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#colorunits) (but not always all the alternative spellings, e.g. "grey" vs "gray").

Answer (score 0):

...

http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=css+named+colors

w3c html/css standards only specify 16 colours:

aqua
black
blue
fuchsia
gray
green
lime
maroon
navy
olive
purple
red
silver
teal
white
yellow

everything else is non-standard - use hexcode instead.

Comment: To whoever downvoted: try cutting newbie some slack.
@fusi:  Just posting an answer pointing to a google search is going to get downvoted.  We want SO to be _the_ go to site for answers not  site contianing links to searches which may have an answer.  You added text to the answer later, had you done so upfront and placed the link at the bottom as reference and included the detail you are refering to strict CSS compliance then this answer may have done better.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use css for gray colors, for example `#ddd`, or `#e4e4e4`,
They'll be gray as long as all three values (rgb) are the equals.

Answer (score 0):

There are now about 168 named colors in CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/named-color.

MDN summarizes the growth in this list:

> Initially, in CSS Level 1, only 16 basic colors were defined, with orange added in CSS Level 2. Web designers found this list too short, and browser vendors added numerous names for colors based on the X11 color names. In SVG 1.0, then in CSS Colors Level 3, these names got standardized, formally defined, and made uniform (some had different spellings that are now aliases). They are called extended color keywords, X11 colors, or SVG colors. In CSS Colors Level 4, an additional color, rebeccapurple was added to honor web pioneer Eric Meyer.